# How to view the size of an AWS backup vault?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

How can I know the data size of my AWS backup vault?

I can't find any instruction to view the data size of the vault in this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/listing-backups.html).

The reason I want to know the data size of the vault is that my AWS Backup costs me too much money. So I'd like to know how much data I've stored in the vault.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The size of the backup vault can be found in RDS -> Snapshots -> Backup service.

If you have more than 1 backup in the vault, the size of the vault would be the sum of the size of all the backups.

[image]

Comment: The question was about AWS Backup vault size  not RDS  snapshot

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to see this easily in the UI. You can see the size of the individual snapshots by going to "AWS Backup" > "My Account" > "Backup Vaults". There, click on the vault you are interested in. Then click on the invididual recovery-points and their respective size is shown. Now add those values.

On the command line using awscli and jq, you can sum them for the whole vault (replace MY_XXX by your specific values):

```
aws backup --region MY_REGION list-recovery-points-by-backup-vault --backup-vault-name MY_BACKUP_VAULT_NAME --query 'RecoveryPoints[*].BackupSizeInBytes' --output json | jq add
```